# How to hide an image appended to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden, styling

I created a rails API backend and am trying to create a memory match card game. From the backend, I am fetching and appending images of Mario characters to a tile div I created in the front end. Currently, the tiles show up with the characters. I want the default action of the "tiles" to be that they show up as just the div with the image hidden, and then I will create an event listener in JS in my frontend for the image to show up if and only if the tile is clicked. I'm not sure if I need to do this in CSS (visiblity: hidden just hides the entire div but I want just the div background color to show without the appended image) or if I should make some type of function in JS to handle this?

Comment: Why not just use `visiblity: hidden` css rule directly on the image like `div img { visiblity: hidden; }` ?

Comment: Hi Alina! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, paste your html, css and js base code where you try to achieve this behavior, to be easier to understand what you have tried. I recommend you to read the guide to [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

jquery solution

```
// replace imageId with your image id selector in your html
$('#imageId').hide();
```

js solution

```
document.getElementById("imageId").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to use jQuery, so a css or pure js solution would be desirable

Comment: i will post a js answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to set fix size for tile div and give background to tile div. and inside tile div put your image by giving style display:none and whenever you click on parent tile div set style of image display:block

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to solve this issue. I will suggest use css to solve it. you create show hide css and toggle on event listener. here is the working example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jfxbgs

//JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tiles p').forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    const img = target.parentNode.querySelector("img")
   if(img.className == "hide")
    img.className = ""
    else 
    img.className = "hide"
  })
})
```

//CSS

```
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.tiles img.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.tiles img {
  visibility: inherit;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="tiles">
    <img class="show" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    <p>title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tiles">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    <p>title</p>
  </div>
<div class="tiles">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    <p>title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```